# Kills backwards at beginning of line

Tags: kill-text

With the cursor set just before B, how would I bring `Bar` next to `Foo`? I tried `C-0 C-k`, no avail.

```
     Foo

Bar
```

Desired:

```
 FooBar
```

Comment: I must be misunderstanding: just hit DEL?

Comment: What if there is a line in between?

Comment: Isn't that a different question? Depending on the circumances, you could use different methods. At the very least, you can do `C-k` to kill `Bar` and then move to the end of `Foo` and yank it with `C-y`.

Comment: Or `C--C-kDEL` (thats Ctrl and then '-')

Comment: The question is not clear, including given the exchange in the Comments (and comments can be deleted at any time). Please clarify - specify just what problem you want solved, and what would a solution consist of (i.e., what you want), excluding all other possibilities of what you might mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the exposed case, the simplest solution will be `C-SPC` `M-b` `M-f` `<delete>` if `delete-active-region` is not `nil`.

If you're looking for something more code-oriented this ad-hoc code should work:

```lisp
(defun join-words-across-lines()
    "Join words across lines."
    (interactive "*")
    (let ((beg (point)))
        (while (not (re-search-backward "[[:word:]]" nil nil 1)))
        (join-line nil (point) beg)
        (delete-horizontal-space)))
```

**But** isn't a perfect solution, just a *different* quick & dirty  approach from the one exposed first, only for ilustrative purposes.

Comment: `join-line` is an alias for `delete-indentation` and takes one argument. What Emacs version are you using?

Comment: 27.0.90.   That's what appears on `describe-function`
(join-line &optional ARG BEG END)

Join this line to previous and fix up whitespace at join.
If there is a fill prefix, delete it from the beginning of this
line.
With prefix ARG, join the current line to the following line.
When BEG and END are non-nil, join all lines in the region they
define.  Interactively, BEG and END are, respectively, the start
and end of the region if it is active, else nil.  (The region is
ignored if prefix ARG is given.)

Comment: Thanks. I guess it won't work with version 26.3 then.

Answer (score 0):

You need some command that deletes all whitespace between two
non-space characters. Here's one:

```lisp
(defun delete-whitespace ()
  (interactive)
  (let (target (chars "[[:space:]\n]"))
    (skip-chars-backward chars)
    (setq target (point))
    (skip-chars-forward chars)
    (while (> (point) target)
      (delete-backward-char 1))))
```

Comment: I'd rely on what emacs environment describes as a word, or whitespace instead defining my own into the function.